# n3 line chart x axis label

Tags: javascript, d3.js, n3-charts

I am using n3 line charts (http://n3-charts.github.io/line-chart/#/) but I am having difficulty looking for a solution on how to make the x axis labels rotate diagonally just like in this example:

http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html

Comment: the example is pretty straightforward.. Maybe you could show us some of your related code snips so we could assist better.

Comment: I tried to edit the file line-chart.js. In the function "computeaxes", after line 1144, that's where I tried to implement the codes specified in d3noob site, which is adding  .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-65)" 
                })

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something along these lines:

```
// X-Axis Font
.x-axis {
    text {
        transform: rotate(340deg);
    }
}
```

You may need to fiddle with the text-anchor, but that will rotate the text.